# Disable and Enable Scroll Window when resizing viewports in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have here a navbar with a dropdown menu and I wanted the page to stop scrolling when I stretch out the whole screen to another resolution. I have reviewed my code and I think the problem is the conditions in my if-else statement. I am stuck in this for hours now and I cannot formulate a solution to my problem. I also added a label in my html `aria-label="hidden"` to use for enabling and disabling the whole page scroll. Can someone enlighten me with this problem I am currently having now?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="c-dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars c-grey-pill"></i></div>
    <div id="c-nav-mobile" aria-label="hidden">
      <ul class="c-nav-links2">
        <li><a href="#">カテゴリ1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">カテゴリ2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">カテゴリ3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">カテゴリ4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="c-img-cont2">
        <div class="c-image-res3"></div>
        <div class="c-consult-cont2">
          <div class="c-con-rel"><span class="c-consult-text2">自分のキャリアに合った留学を選ぶための無料相談会実施中</span>
            <button class="c-btn c-btn-primary consult-text">詳しくはこちら→</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my jquery code for this:

```
$('.c-dropdown-btn i').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-times');
    $('#c-nav-mobile').fadeToggle("on");
    bodyStyle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    bodyStyle();
});
function bodyStyle() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var navMobile = $("#c-nav-mobile");

    if(viewportWidth < 768 && navMobile.attr("aria-label") == "hidden") {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        console.log("abc");
    } else if (viewportWidth > 769 && navMobile.attr("aria-label") == "hidden"){
        $("body").css("overflow", "none");
        console.log("123");
    }
}
```

for scss snippet (for `#c-nav-mobile`)

```
#c-{
&nav-mobile {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 41px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 523px;
    padding: 25px 32px 34px 31px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    @include mq('md') {
        display: none !important;
    }
    &.on {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

}

I declared a function and called it inside resize and also to my click event.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Comment: posted already @BrentStees

Answer (score 0):

#c-nav-mobile add this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries do most of the work for you.

You can eliminate much of the JS here by using css rules inside a class. Then only use JS to toggle the tag - which you are already doing but do so on the body tag.

HTML (just added the body tag for completeness)

```
<body>
  <div class="c-dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars c-grey-pill"></i></div>
    <div id="c-nav-mobile" aria-label="hidden">
      <ul class="c-nav-links2">
      <li><a href="#">カテゴリ1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">カテゴリ2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">カテゴリ3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">カテゴリ4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="c-img-cont2">
      <div class="c-image-res3"></div>
      <div class="c-consult-cont2">
        <div class="c-con-rel"><span class="c-consult-text2">自分のキャリアに合った留学を選ぶための無料相談会実施中</span>
        <button class="c-btn c-btn-primary consult-text">詳しくはこちら→</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
// code below works if it's the body that is doing the scrolling
// if not, use the scrolling element instead here and the JS click

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body.fa-times {
    overflow: hidden;

    // might need to set a height
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$('.c-dropdown-btn i').click(function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('fa-times');
    $('#c-nav-mobile').fadeToggle("on");
});
```